# Есть ли разница в программах Unity?

Tags: unity3d

Наблюдаю у друга его работу в программе Unity 2018.4(и еще какие то цифры). Но ведь есть уже 2020 версия.

1. Разве в 2018 версии есть те функции, которых нет в версиях 2019 и 2020?
2. Есть ли смысл скачивать Unity 2020.1 Beta?
3. Будут ли открываться проекты 2018 версии на 2019/2020?
4. Будут ли открываться проекты из 2020 версии, в версиях ниже?

Answer (score 0):

Чаще всего проекты предыдущих версий открываются без проблем, но с некоторыми версиями случаются разное. Обновления не всегда связаны с инструментами юнити, выход новой версий `iOS` и `Android`, операционок консолей, bugfix и т.д.

Например если я не ошибаюсь проект из под версии `2017` под `iOS` уже не запустятся, а при переноси на новые версии придётся дополнительно возиться с настройками `XCode`. Это самая штормящая платформа, где изменения довольно часты. Поэтому говоря о мобильной платформе актуальность важна.

С `Android` попроще, если таргет версия 4.4, которая абсолютна совместима с современными.

С `Widows` и консолями всё тоже просто.

Answer (score 0):

1. Нет, однако 2020 версия на данный момент имеет ряд багов
2. Alpha/Beta/Preview версии смысла скачивать для разработки нет, разве что пощупать новый функционал
3. Скорее всего да (но лучше сделать бекап, о чем Unity попросит при попытке открыть проект), возможно, придется исправить устаревший код
4. Скорее всего нет, разве что 2020 проект запустится на 2019, ниже - вряд ли из-за старой файловой системы

Comment: тогда какую версию скачивать? Чтобы максимально новая была и без багов

Comment: @Exqualater, баги есть в любой версии, 2019.3 - последняя релизная версия.

Comment: то есть там минимум багов?

Comment: @Exqualater почитайте, что такое релизная версия ПО.